# Add stream to StreamZip list

Tags: flutter

I don't know how to add streams in a list that will be used by a StreamZip and later used in a StremBuilder.

```
List _streams = [];


for (var i = 0; i < _chunks.length; i++) {
  Stream stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .where('uid', whereIn: _chunks[i])
      .snapshots();
  setState(() {
    _streams.add(stream);
  });
}


StreamZip myStreams = StreamZip(_streams);
```

`The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Stream<dynamic>>'`

Or any other way of combining streams dynamically would be ok. I don't have to use `StreamZip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SteamZip` takes `Iterable<Stream<dynamic>>`, and you declared `_streams` as `List`.
Do this instead:

```
List<Stream<dynamic>> _streams = [];
...
StreamZip myStreams = StreamZip(_streams);
```

Comment: I get this: The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'List<R> Function<R>()'.
Try defining the operator '<'.

Comment: Sorry ... I don't know how to do this either. But it's returning this ; The argument type 'List<Iterable<Stream<dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Stream<dynamic>>'.

Comment: Thank you ... it worked. Do you have any examples of how it can be used in a Streambuilder?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Fluttery myself, I don't know if I could help you with that.